# React how to pass state without rendering component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, parameters, react-router

I have an issue where when I start at the root and click through the links all the states load in fine but when I got to copy and paste the URL into a new window it doesnt show, would I be right to assume its because the previous component isnt being rendered to set the state?

Hopefully someone can point me to some helpful articles or even have experienced this before?

Here is a link to a screen recording I made to better show what I mean https://youtu.be/M0390D4oJDg

**CODE**

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation, useParams } from "react-router";
import PostBlock from "./PostBlock";




const PostList = () => {
  const {thread} = useParams()
  const { state: { description, title } = {} } = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="m-10 flex justify-center">
        <div style={{ width: "1216px" }}>
          <div className="flex justify-center">
            <div className="flex-1 justify-center mb-5 p-5 h-64 border border-gray-300">
              <div>{title}</div>
              <div>{description}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <table className="min-w-full table-auto">
            <thead className="justify-between">
              <tr className="bg-gray-800">
                <th className="px-8 py-2 text-left text-white">Posts</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody className="bg-gray-200">
              <PostBlock thread={thread}/>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostList;
```

**LINK**

```
 <Link to={{ pathname: `/thread/${thread}`, state: {title: title, description: description} }}>
```

**URL**

```
http://localhost:3000/thread/jxvgOKPrSiCnI2ocDxgJ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *This react stuff is harder than I initially thought*

Don't give up easily. It's one of the beautiful things!

---

Start with optional chaining.

```js
const title = useLocation()?.state?.title;
const description = useLocation()?.state?.description;
```

If this is not supported, use `&&`:

```js
const title = useLocation() && useLocation().state && useLocation().state.title;
const description = useLocation() && useLocation().state && useLocation().state.description;
```

And only when `title` and `description` is not `null`, render your contents.

```js
const PostList = () => {
  const { thread } = useParams();
  const title = useLocation() && useLocation().state && useLocation().state.title;
  const description = useLocation() && useLocation().state && useLocation().state.description;

  return title && description ? <div></div> : null;
};
```

Now the code will not render the content until and unless both the values are set. And this will make sure your code loads without any errors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and the motivation I will test this out!

Comment: The Antonio the other commenter had a clean solution to stopping it from crashing, but I still dont get the state I made a little recording https://youtu.be/M0390D4oJDg to maybe better explain my issue

Comment: @Erykj97 Got it. Can you send me the code in say, https://CodeSandbox.io? I am ready to check it out in depth.

Comment: Thank you so much, https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-sea-z9wdb?file=/src/App.js sorry about the missing style

Comment: @Erykj97 Checking now.

Comment: @Erykj97 I am able to get it working fine... I refresh and I still get it.

Comment: But I am pretty sure, @Erykj97, `state: {title: title, description: description}` gets lost when you refresh. But at the moment, help me to repro the error on the CSB. I am unable to make it not work. Refreshing or anything, it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes sir I have fixed the actual error, that appear, my issue is like you said on refresh state gets lost on localhost

Comment: @Erykj97 Looks like this is not happening on csb right?

Comment: Its not, I think I will have to possibly throw the code up on a server and see if it works fine, thanks for all your time. the issue might be just me testing on localhost

Comment: @Erykj97 Feel free to ask again once, I'll be glad to help. This seems like an issue that most developers need to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused as to what your question really is, but you've got some issues with your code. Try this:

```js
const PostList = () => {
  const { thread } = useParams();
  const { state: { description, title } = {} } = useLocation();

  return <div></div>;
};
```

There is no reason to initialize `useLocation()` twice. You could've also initialized it into one constant and then access description and state through it.

```js
const PostList = () => {
  const { thread } = useParams();
  const location = useLocation();

  console.log(location.state.title, location.state.description);

  return <div></div>;
};
```

Additionally, you can incorporate `object?.property` method as a failsafe if your state is empty:

`console.log(location?.state?.title);`

Take a look at proper `useLocation` usage [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/hooks.md#uselocation)

Comment: Thank you, for the tips, I have changed the way useLocation is initialized to the way you showed now I no longer get an error but the state still doesnt show, I have just done a quick screen recording of what I mean because I find it hard to explain in words =>  https://youtu.be/M0390D4oJDg